# Динамическое создание объектов в Spring

Tags: java, spring, swing

Только осваиваюсь в Spring.
Подскажите, как реализовать следующее:
Есть основная панель:

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

    public class BasicFrame extends JFrame
    {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(BasicFrame.class.getName());
    private JButton button;
    private JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    private int i;

    public BasicFrame(JButton button, JTabbedPane tabbedPane)
    {
            this.button = button;
            this.tabbedPane = tabbedPane;

            button.setText("Добавить панель");
            button.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) ->
            {
                tabbedPane.add(new PanelTest(i));
                i++;
            });

            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setSize(500, 400);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }
    }
```

Есть панель, которую необходимо динамически создавать, добавлять в базовую панель и хранить в Spring, сейчас она создается на слушателе кнопки через new:
        import java.util.logging.Logger;
        import javax.swing.JButton;
        import javax.swing.JPanel;

```
    public class PanelTest extends JPanel
    {
        private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(PanelTest.class.getName());
        private JButton button;

        public PanelTest(int number)
        {
            button = new JButton(String.valueOf(number));
            add(button);
        }
    }
```

xml настройки Spring следующие:

```
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd
    ">

        <bean id="buttonAdd" class="javax.swing.JButton"/>
        <bean id="tabbedPane" class="javax.swing.JTabbedPane"/>
        <bean id="basicFrame" class="ru.ezhov.BasicFrame">
            <constructor-arg ref="buttonAdd"/>
            <constructor-arg ref="tabbedPane"/>
        </bean>

    </beans>
```

А так же, как из панели PanelTest получить базовую панель из Spring?
Спасибо!

Comment: На мой взгляд вы выбрали не удачный пример для освоения spring. Spring это в первую очередь DI контейнер. И большинство бинов существуют в единственном числе и имеют глобальную видимость в контейнере. Для создания интерфейса это помеха, так много элементов буду "загрязнять" пространство имён. Более удачным решением будет укрупнить бины, т.е. один бин - это крупная компонента со множеством элементов.

Comment: Так и есть, к примеру PanelTest содержит огромное кол-во всяких компонентов, как из этих компонентов обратиться к контексту и взять BasicFrame?  Правильно ли будет сделать ApplicationContext Singleton-ом и по мере необходимости его дергать? А так же взаимодействие между компонентами тогда писать на чистой java без Spring?

Comment: зачем вам в компонентах обращаться к BasicFrame? Spring и так чистая java.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman действительно, в реальных проектах незачем, это просто пример приведен. Немного перефразирую основной для меня  вопрос. Есть модель для JList, делается единоразово и потом просто перезагружается по какому либо событию и есть несколько JList, которые ее используют. Правильно как сделать так: Инициализировать ее сразу и дать спискам? А потом в списках через getModel() обращаться? И читал, что в бизнес бинах не стоит обращаться к контексту, но если нужно получить контекст, как тогда правильно сделать?

Comment: если ваша цель научиться spring, то вы выбрали неподходящий способ. и СО это не форум - это сайт вопросов и ответов. на ваш вопрос хороший ответ дать сложно.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman спасибо

Comment: для UI посмотрите на MVC